# Get all simple products of a category including not visible individually products - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, category, collection

I need to get all simple products of a category. By using the following code, I'm getting only products which has visibility of **Catalog, Search** but not **Not Visible Individually** products.

```
$categoryId = 12;
$categoryFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
$category = $categoryFactory->create()
    ->load($categoryId)
    ->getProductCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', 'simple');
```

I need all simple products regardless of its visibility. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try This :-**

**Visibility Ids**

> VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE = 1;
>
> VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG = 2;
>
> VISIBILITY_IN_SEARCH = 3;
>
> VISIBILITY_BOTH = 4;

```
$categoryId = '12';
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$categoryCollection = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');

    $category = $categoryCollection->create()->load($categoryId);
    $collection = $productCollection->create()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
                    ->addCategoryFilter($category);
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', array('eq' => array(2,3))); //you can pass id as per your requirement
```

Comment: I said I need both "Catalog, Search" and "Not Visible Individually" simple products. But you are applying filter to get only "Catalog, Search" products.

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: @VinothSelvi have you gotten both  "Catalog, Search" and "Not Visible Individually" simple products.

i want to get both but can't

Comment: @HafizArslan yes I got all simple products using the above solution.

Comment: please attach your code @Hafiz Arslan

Comment: i am not getting "VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE" items.

Answer (score 0):

```
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
```

Try this one, may help you

Comment: No change in result. Getting on visible products.